# Unexpected behavior from applying ToRadicals to eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I am trying to get the symbolic form of a $10 \times 10$ matrix (I know, that is generally too large).

```
mat = 
  {{-6 a, -3 b, 0, 0, -3 b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-Sqrt[3] b, 5 a, -2 b, 0, -b, -Sqrt[2] b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, -2 b, 8 a, -Sqrt[3] b, 0, -Sqrt[2] b, -b, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, -Sqrt[3] b, 15 a, 0, 0, -Sqrt[3] b, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-Sqrt[3] b, -b, 0, 0, 5 a, -Sqrt[2] b, 0, -2 b, 0, 0}, 
   {0, -Sqrt[2] b, -Sqrt[2] b, 0, -Sqrt[2] b, 5 a, -Sqrt[2] b, 
    -Sqrt[2] b, -Sqrt[2] b, 0}, 
   {0, 0, -b, -Sqrt[3] b, 0, -Sqrt[2] b, 9 a, 0, -2 b, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, -2 b, -Sqrt[2] b, 0, 8 a, -b, -Sqrt[3] b}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Sqrt[2] b, -2 b, -b, 9 a, -Sqrt[3] b}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Sqrt[3] b, -b Sqrt[3], 15 a}};

  ToRadicals @ Eigenvalues[mat]
```

It provides 6 of the 10 solutions, but then appears to go South.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to show all 10 eigenvalues in symbolic form?

Have yet to try for the eigenvectors.

Comment: Honestly I am surprised that you get as many as six in radical form! Finding the eigenvalues of `mat` is formally equivalent to finding the roots of its characteristic polynomial, which has degree 10. There is no guarantee that the roots of such a polynomial can be expressed as radicals at all, so the fact that you can get some of them as radicals already seems pretty lucky to me. Do you have reason to believe that they should all be expressible as radicals? Can you make any assumptions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Actually, you get only 4 of them in radical form. If  `eig = ToRadicals@Eigenvalues[mat]`, we can look at `eig[[1;;4]]` and see that the have the same form while `eig[[5;;]]` all have the same form and are not "radicalizable".

Comment: To confirm @Runny's observation in another way, `Factor[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x]]` gives a quartic and a sextic factor; feeding the quartic factor into `Solve[]` does yield four radical expressions, while the roots of the sextic do not yield to `ToRadicals[]`. (That is, there might in fact be radical expressions, but *Mathematica* is not smart enough to find them.)

Comment: @MarcoB: $a, b$ are real constants. I thought the structure and all the zeros of the matrix might lead to a solution, but that it was a wild stretch from my initial statement. Thanks all for the nice comments.